# Webpage showing data - Data updated meanwhile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 website and I have a regular page showing some data. I want to add a similar feature like SO has, which notifies the user that another user has made some changes (database record update) since the page was opened.

What's the best practice to achieve it? I don't know if the most common approach is to use timers, or if is there any other option like listeners.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too familiar with ASP.NET MVC 4 so this answer is from an design PoV.

Basically there are 2 solutions:

- Have the server inform (all) clients that the data has changed (reverse AJAX, Listeners/Observers)
- Have the client regularly ask the server if the data has changed (Timer)

in 99.9% of the cases you want to pick option 2. Keeping track of all clients and managing that list creates too many problems worth the effort. while receiving an additional request every x seconds hardly ever kills you (as long as x is proportional to your server and customer base).

Comment: Ok, that was my idea. Stack Overflow probably uses also timers. Thanks